# Enhance Apply Speed on Big Dataset

Tags: r, performance, plyr

Hi I'm try to speed up a ddly function.

Here is the (big) datastet I use :

```
df<-data.frame(code_client=as.factor(sample(177563:(1013643+177563),810805,T)),annee=sample(c(2012,2013),810805,T))
```

First try :

```
system.time(ca_annee1<- ddply(.data = df, 
                .variables = .(code_client,annee), 
                .fun=nrow,
                .progress = progress_text(char = ".")))

# user   system  elapsed 
# 1439.278    1.774 1441.876
```

It's really slow, I just want to count each combination between clode_client and annee.

I tried to use my 4cores:

```
library(doSNOW)
registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(4, type = "SOCK"))
system.time(ca_annee2<- ddply(.data = df, 
                             .variables = .(code_client,annee), 
                             .fun=nrow,
                             .parallel=TRUE))
#user   system  elapsed 
#2054.860   13.618 2080.125
```

Tt's even more slow, why? (My cores where all 100% during calculation)

Anyway, I find a way to do this faster (quite instantly):

```
ca2013<-data.frame(nombre_visite=summary(subset(df,annee==2013)$code_client,maxsum=9e9))
ca2013$code_client<-rownames(ca2013)
ca2013$annee<-2013
ca2012<-data.frame(nombre_visite=summary(subset(df,annee==2013)$code_client,maxsum=9e9))
ca2012$code_client<-rownames(ca2012)
ca2012$annee<-2012
ca_annee3<-rbind(ca2012,ca2013)
```

But I would like to find a way to user ddply( or agregate, or by or apply, wathever), because the summary trick will not be ok in other context.

So does anyone understand why the paralell approach is slower? And does someone give me some tips to boost the plyr functions ?

Regards

Comment: If you want speed, don't use `ddply`; switch to either the **data.table** or **dplyr** packages.

Comment: `library(data.table); setDT(df); df[,list(Count=.N),keyby=c("code_client","annee")]
` ?

Comment: If you "just want to count each comibinaison between clode_client and annee", why not start with `table`? `system.time(t <- table(df$code_client, df$annee))`. user: 1.43;  system: 0.10; elapsed: 1.53, on my quite ordinary laptop.

Comment: I think the parallel approach may be slower because it creates multiple copies of the dataset